# IP vs Server/machine name - WCF hosted on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ip, iis-7.5

I created and deployed WCF service and web application(client) on IIS 7.5
problem : config of the client referring to the end point as ex: http://(IP address)/app/abc.svc this works fine. when i try to change IP address to Server Machine name(ex:http://machinename/app/abc.svc) its unable to access to the service.
requirement: i need configure with machine name not with IP address.

Comment: In a Windows environment, when you access a machine by machine name only you either need to use WINS/NetBIOS (legacy) or have the client configured with a DNS suffix search list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your network setup. Is it safe to assume the client who's trying to access your service inside the same domain as you? You can check your [NetBIOS name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#NetBIOS_name), as Chris said, to verify you're using the right name to access your machine. Check it from their location to see how it shows up from their machine.

The other, simpler option, would be to edit the client's [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29). Add an entry to go from whatever name you want to your ip. The only issue with that is whether there will be multiple machines accessing it, but if that's the case maybe it's worth registering a dns.